# How to return value of items in Listbox to Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

my situation is that I need to add up all prices of items in a `Listbox` and have the total price in the textbox. I am using c# WinForms. This what I have so far but it is not working correctly by showing total, it is showing the price of the last item I press and not the total of all items

```
public class SelectedPizza
    {
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public string Format() => $"{Size} {Name} {Price}"; // Format inside Listbox
    }
    private void ButtonSizeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        _selectedPizza.Size = button.Tag.ToString(); // Adds pizza size to order listbox

        if (_selectedPizza.Name != null)
            _selectedPizza.Price = GetPrice(_selectedPizza.Size);
    }

    private void ButtonNameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        _selectedPizza.Name = button.Tag.ToString();

        if (_selectedPizza.Size != null)
            _selectedPizza.Price = GetPrice(_selectedPizza.Size);

        listBox1.Items.Add(_selectedPizza.Format()); // Adds pizza name to order listbox
    }
private string GetPrice(string sSize)
        {
            string sPrice = "0.00";

        if (sSize == "Large")
            sPrice = "11.90";

        TxtbxTotal.Text = sPrice;  // Displays price in order total textbox
        return sPrice;
    }
```

Comment: `TxtbxTotal.Text = sPrice;` What do you think this line does?

Comment: Please share a [mcve], including how that method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't go deep into your problem but I will address the main question.

Finally, you want to **sum up the Listbox items**.

So to do that, add the below piece to your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listboxname.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
   sum += Convert.ToDecimal(listboxname.Items[i].Text);
} 
textBoxtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

> I roughly read the entire code and couldn't find any event relating to total of the listbox. Maybe you missed to write the click event of the total button.

Comment: thanks alot. I thought that this would do it:
        TxtbxTotal.Text = sPrice;
        return sPrice;

Comment: it is saying that the line: sum += Convert.ToDecimal(listboxname.Items[i].Text); is not in the correct format and is not accepting ".text" in that line

Comment: @MasonBoce: Try changing `.Text` to `.ToString()`

Comment: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' for line sum+= Convert.ToDecimal(listboxname.Items[i].ToString());

Comment: @MasonBoce: Buddy, a short mistake out there. Are you trying to convert name(`listboxname.Items[i]`) to double? Name will include words and words cannot be converted to double! I think that you have size, name and price in the same listbox. In that case, make sure those are seperated by a space and then use `listboxname.Items[i].ToString().Split(' ')[2]`

Answer (score 0):

you seem writing a decent program but you are killing it doing this `listBox1.Items.Add(_selectedPizza.Format());`

you need to use this technology

```cs
public interface IFoodItem // all list box items must have certain properties
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Price { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; }
}

public class Pizza : FoodItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Display 
    {
        get { return $"{Size} {Name} {Price}"; }
    }
}
// another example
public class Sandwhich : FoodItem
{
 // . . . .  .
}


//. . . .  . .
// Get the list
var listData = new List<IFoodItem>();
listData.Add( . . . );
// . . . .  . 

// this is how you should set the list - DataSource always last
lstList.ValueMember = "Id";
lstList.DisplayMember = "Display";
lstList.DataSource = listData;

// Get selected item info
IFoodItem item = (IFoodItem)lstList.SelectedItem;
txtItemPrice.Text = item.Price;

// Get Total using LINQ
txtTOTALPrice.Text = ((List<IFoodItem>)lstList.DataSource).Sum(item => item.Price);
```

#### UPDATE

**From OP:** *"i have to stick to a specification for school, so all I need to know is how to do it with the code that I have got already"*

your value is `public string Format() => $"{Size} {Name} {Price}";` added here `listBox1.Items.Add(_selectedPizza.Format());`

In this case you do this (your sum is third part of the string item in the list)

```cs
var sum = 0m;
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
{ 
    string[] itemParts  = 
        ((string)item).Split(default(char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // price is last index
    sum += decimal.Parse(itemParts[itemParts.Length - 1]); // get last item
} 
txtTotal.Text = sum;
```

**Here is the working unit test**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var list = new List<object>();
        list.Add("aaa xxx 5 10.99");
        list.Add("bbb yyy 7 11.99");
        list.Add("ccc zzz 8 12.99");
        var sum = 0m;
        foreach (object item in list)
        { 
            string[] itemParts  = 
                ((string)item).Split(default(char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // price's index is 2
            sum += decimal.Parse(itemParts[itemParts.Length - 1]);
        } 
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this code. i just want a textbox to add up the total price of items in listbox

Comment: @MasonBoce how are you going to do that? By parsing a string from a text list item? you can do if you want to. But my code shows that list items should be objects, not strings. Then you can get over each object , get its price and make a sum

Comment: how would I do it without the new code is all I want to know

Comment: @MasonBoce adapt new code. My example shows exactly how it works. You can do way more with  objects as list items than strings

Comment: i have to stick to a specification for school, so all I need to know is how to do it with the code that I have got already please if you can help

Comment: i am getting an error when using your updated code saying that 'the input string was not in the correct format' for code: sum += decimal.Parse(itemParts[2]);

Comment: also it is not counting the first items price in listbox and crashes after a few items are entered

Comment: Must the price index be 2?

Comment: @MasonBoce This is exactly why I showed to you how to do it like a pro.... your item is `$"{Size} {Name} {Price}"` right? In this case you need to take last item separated by `" "`. I see. You probably have a space in the name. Let me fix it for you now. Only change is this - `decimal.Parse(itemParts[itemParts.Length - 1])` get last index dynamically instead of fixed (2)

Comment: thanks so much however the first item that is added to the listbox is not being added but everything else is fine

Comment: @MasonBoce when it comes to programming, I don't believe in magic